# Maven Produced JAR Will Not Run Because of Exec Error

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project that builds and works just fine on my other computer (a Windows machine). I transferred the source over to a Mac machine, re-packaged, and cannot get the program JAR produced by maven to run due to the following error:

```
zsh: exec format error: lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
```

The JAR you see mentioned above is one of many dependencies of my program. I am unsure what would cause this error. I have made sure that java is properly setup on the system, and maven as well. All JARs have execute permissions. I am able to create and run other maven projects (without dependencies) just fine, but this one seems to just not want to work. What could be the issue?

java and maven version outputs (yes, I know I'm using an old version of Java):

```
java version "1.8.0_321"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_321-b07)
```

```
Apache Maven 3.8.4 (9b656c72d54e5bacbed989b64718c159fe39b537)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.8.4/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_321, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_321.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "12.0.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding dependencies as jars in a lib directory when you are using maven?
Can't you just add the dependencies to your pom.xml?

Comment: I followed some earlier tutorials on how to include JARs in my project that are needed by the program. They suggested using the maven-dependency-plugin, which is what I use and then include the dependency JARs in the classpath when running the program. This works just fine in Windows, I don't understand why this wouldn't work in Mac.